# Auto backup PostgreSQL Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, backup, odoo

I want to do the work of automatic storage for the database " Postgress "
I looked on the Internet and found that it must be installed pgAgent
I want to do this program for odoo 8 because I used the Windows

I wanted to prove to Odoo 8  but when I install the module AUTO BACKUP while it have Bug  pysftp

> 'This module needs pysftp to automaticly write backups to the FTP through SFTP. Please install pysftp on your system. (sudo pip install pysftp)'

I did not know how I install the Auto backup for odoo or For postgress
Important for me How do I create automatic storage on the database Postgress